# How to disable next URL parameter while using login_required decorator in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, django-3.0

I have the following project folder structure in Django:

```
.
|_blog/
|_django_blog/
|_users/
|_manage.py
```

I have the following in django_blog/urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
    path('profile/',user_views.profile,name='profile'),
    path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),name='logout'),
]
```

And I have the following decorated view in users/views.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request,'users/profile.html')
```

And following constants in django_blog/settings.py:

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Now if user is not logged in and tries to access `/profile/` URL he will be redirected to login page with `next=/profile/` paramter passed in to the URL. After the user signs in, it redirects the user to `/profile/`. But I want the user to be redirected to the homepage instead which is the default behaviour of signing in from `/login/` URL. How should I implement that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `redirect_field_name` argument to `None` :

```py
@login_required(redirect_field_name=None)
def profile(request):
    return render(request,'users/profile.html')
```

Comment: Could you please also explain how to specify a redirect URL upon sign in from a non-signed-in user on /profile page?